# Find incorrect data in mysql column

Tags: mysql

I have a table with a column that is supposed to have only numbers in it. However, it's possible for the source data to have incorrect data like words in that column.

So the column is represented as VARCHAR so that the data import from CSV doesn't crash.

I need to find just words in that column so I can create an update that replaces them with the correct number.

I started creating query that excludes certain numbers, but it's getting too long and there are too many rows.

```
SELECT ID,LinkedAccountId,Engagement FROM billing_info WHERE Engagement != '803000006530' AND Engagement != '807000000401' AND Engagement != '403000001956' AND Engagement != '28211756' AND Engagement != '807000000345' AND  Engagement != '800000026680' AND Engagement != '807000000351' AND Engagement != '807000000356' AND Engagement != '3000139146' AND Engagement != '807000000394' AND Engagement != '807000000041' AND Engagement != '808000000220' AND Engagement != '807000000396' AND Engagement != '807000000397' AND Engagement != '807000000340' AND Engagement != '807000000398' AND Engagement != '870000000403' AND Engagement != '28200598' AND Engagement != '403000002065' AND Engagement != '807000000398' AND Engagement != '2000549001' AND LinkedAccountId = '12345678919';
```

The data comes back like this and I need to keep adding numbers to exclude:

```
| 3696724 | 123456789101    | 807000000381 |
| 3696817 | 123456789101    | 800000032764 |
| 3697085 | 123456789101    | complexity   |
| 3697088 | 123456789101    | complexity   |
| 3697089 | 123456789101    | complexity   |
| 3697100 | 123456789101    | complexity   |
| 3697107 | 123456789101    | complexity   |
| 3697115 | 123456789101    | complexity   |
| 3697137 | 123456789101    | complexity   |
| 3697155 | 123456789101    | complexity   |
| 3697194 | 123456789101    | complexity   |
| 3697205 | 123456789101    | 808000000239 |
| 3697236 | 123456789101    | complexity   |
+---------+-----------------+--------------+
```

I can select for just the word `complexity' but there may be hundreds of other words in there that I don't know yet.

How can I create a query that will select JUST words in this field of text?

Comment: I think something like `CAST(CAST(x AS SIGNED) AS CHAR) != x` should work.

Comment: Before this query gets completely out of hand, learn about `WHERE Engagement NOT IN ('807000000041', '808000000220', ...)`

Comment: Hint: Use `RLIKE`.

Comment: Thanks! RLIKE does the trick. You should put that as an answer so I can accept it.